# Back button handler does not get invoked react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am facing this weired issue with android back button handler. Consider I have 3 screens, A, B, and C. I am using stack navigator. A navigates to B, which navigates to C.

I want to be able to go back from C to B, but not from B to A. For this, in B, I do this:

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      BackHandler.addEventListener(
        "hardwareBackPress",
        this.onBackButtonPressAndroid.bind(this)
      );
    }
 }
 
 onBackButtonPressAndroid = () => {
    Alert.alert("Backed"); //this is just to test
    return true; //make it true to prevent going back
  };
```

And in C:

```js
 if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      BackHandler.addEventListener(
        "hardwareBackPress",
        this.onBackButtonPressAndroid.bind(this)
      );
    }

onBackButtonPressAndroid = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
    return true;
  };
```

I have removed the event listener in `componentWillUnmount`.

When I go from A to B, and press back button, it behaves correctly: it does not go back to A, and I see the alert.

But then when I go from B to C, then combe back to B (using back button), if I again press back button, it goes back to A and I don't see the alert.

Why is that happening?

**Update**
If I don not set the event handler in C, then when I press back button, I see the alert! that means the handlers in B gets called!

Answer (score 2):

Add/remove the event listener based on the [navigation lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html), rather than the component lifecycle. The event listener should not be necessary in C.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Alert, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation'

export default class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  onBackPressAndroid = () => {
    Alert.alert('Cannot go back')
    return true
  }

  didFocus = () => BackHandler.addEventListener(
    'hardwareBackPress',
    this._onBackPressAndroid
  )

  willBlur = () => BackHandler.removeEventListener(
    'hardwareBackPress',
    this._onBackPressAndroid
  )

  render() {
    <>
      { Platform.OS === 'android'
        <NavigationEvents
          onDidFocus={this.didFocus}
          onWillBlur={this.willBlur}
        />
      }
      { /* your component render */ }
    </>
  }
}
```

Comment: @Rakib Can you show your render function and the error?

Comment: Thanks @zyntrix. I could find and solve the compilation error. But I need to understand why my original code did not work, and why this will work, since originally I faced the issue at random times.

Comment: It is due to the fact that Components do not unmount when being added to the navigation stack. The `BackHandler` is independent of the Component, so when navigating to C, the `BackHandler` from B was still active. By adding/removing the event listeners on the navigation lifecycle instead, it ensures that the event listener is only active while that screen is displayed.

Comment: Thanks @zyntrix. I implemented backbutton behavior the way you have specified in every screens in my app. Unfortunately, I still failed to prevent from going back in certain pages.

Comment: @Rakib ensure that the back handling is done at the top level component of a screen. `NavigationEvents` will only work in components that have access to `this.props.navigation`, which `react-navigation` puts in components directly defined as screens when creating the navigators.